# htaccess redirection using the same name?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, http-status-code-301

I have a rather stupid htaccess question that i would be grateful if you could help me out with.

I have an existing page on a site called contactus.php which is accessible at domain.com/contactus.php.

I want to add a redirect so you can visit domain.com/contactus which will show the contents of domain.com/contactus.php. I also want to add a 301 redirect to domain.com/contactus.php to redirect to domain.com/contactus (so whichever one you visit you see domain.com/contactus in the browser, showing content from domain.com/contactus.php).

I would have though the following code should do this, when visiting /contactus.php it's correctly 301 redirecting to /contactus but then i get an infinite redirection error. Shouldn't the 'RewriteCond' prevent the first rule being run again and hence prevent the infinite loop?

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/contactus$
RewriteRule ^contactus.php?$ /contactus [NC,R=301]
RewriteRule ^contactus?$ /contactus.php [NC,L]
```

Thanks everyone,

Dave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(contact)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^contactus/?$ /contactus.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your speedy (and correct!) response, that's greatly appreciated. I understand the logic behind your code but would you be so kind to explain why my original rules were looping, just so that i understand the problem for the future! Thanks so much

Comment: You're welcome, glad it worked out. Yes sure I can explain a bit. Main difference is use of `%{THE_REQUEST}` which doesn't change its value by application of various rules. If you use `%{REQUEST_URI}` OR `%{QUERY_STRING}` then it will cause looping as those variable change their value after application of various rules.

Comment: Ah okay i see, thanks so much that makes sense! So the rest of the logic was correct, it was just the REQUEST_URI that was causing the loop? Thanks anubhava

Comment: Yes that's true. Value of `REQUEST_URI` variable changes in contrast to `THE_REQUEST`.

Comment: Thanks anubhava, that's very much appreciated, good to know i wasn't too far off! Thanks again for your help